# getenv returns null when asked for the username?

Tags: c, windows, getenv

I want to get the username using the `stdlib` functio  `getenv ()`However I always get `NULL` here is the code that I have written:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

 main()
 {

 char *hai;
 printf("The current User name is\n");
 hai="USER";
 printf("%s\n",getenv(hai));


exit(0);
}
```

Does the value that `getenv ()` returns depends on the machine that you are using to compile your code, and why the value returned is `NULL`?

Comment: `getenv` gets an environment variable. Are you sure it works fine on Windows?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: getenv works on Windows. But Windows doesn't define $USER.

Comment: Shouldn't it be USERNAME on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you'll need to use `getenv("USERNAME")`. The `USER`/`USERNAME` environment variable is not standardized, and you won't find an environment variable named `USER` on Windows unless you set it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) talks about the return value for `getenv()`: "A C-string with the value of the requested environment variable, or a null pointer if such environment variable does not exist."

It looks like your "USER" environment variable is not set. Does it show up if you type `set` on the command line?

Comment: Does it mean that if I am running my code under Windows I need to write "USERNAME" but If I am running it under LINUX I need to specify "USER" right?

Comment: @user1680944 That is correct. You can type `set` in a console/terminal window and see all the environment variables that are currently set. On Windows you'll see "USERNAME", and I believe (though I did not check) that you will see "USER" in Linux.